# Android Google Maps satellite view turns black when zooming in

Tags: android, google-maps, satellite

I use the Google Maps with satellite view which usually works fine. Now I've the following problem: When I zoom in very far the whole map turns black.

It only happens in some areas (my case: Stevens Point, Wisconsin, USA), but not in other areas like Germany. This suggests that Google doesn't have the specific satellite data there (the same problem occurs in the MapsDemo by Google too, thus it can't be a code problem). The real Maps App by Google works fine (it just gets fuzzy), how do they handle it? Does anyone had a similar problem?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvG4G.png

Comment: Google probably has access to more data than they give through their API, so you may just need to accept that you may not be able to zoom as far as you like.

Comment: Which is acceptable, but I'd like to prevent the app from showing everything in black. The official Google Maps can do it...

Comment: I have the same problem - also in some areas in Germany. Would be really nice to at least detect that this is happening to perhaps prevent this zoom level in these areas. Best would be if Google stretches the data they have to this zoom-level - just no black which gives really no orientation at all ..